# Customize attribute on type to expect methods marked with another attribute

Tags: c#, attributes

I'm trying to create a custom attribute on a type that expects some properties inside this type to be marked with another attribute, similar to how it is done with `ServiceContract` in [WCF](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf):

```cs
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITestServiceContract
{
    [OperationContract]
    void SomeOperation();
}
```

If no method in a `ServiceContract` is marked with the `OperationContract` attribute, the following warning is shown:

> Interface 'ITestServiceContract' is marked as ServiceContract but doesn't contain any operation contracts

When looking at the [implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/f0b3b4935eb97807dbed7b73f25fbf160a523eac/src/System.Private.ServiceModel/src/System/ServiceModel/ServiceContractAttribute.cs) of the `ServiceContract` I can't see where this would be defined:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(ServiceModelAttributeTargets.ServiceContract, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class ServiceContractAttribute : Attribute
{
    ...
}
```

`ServiceModelAttributeTargets.ServiceContract` is defined externally:

```cs
public const AttributeTargets ServiceContract = AttributeTargets.Interface | AttributeTargets.Class;
```

Is there any way for me to define an attribute like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You usually don't define that kind of logic in the attribute itself. The attribute usually just "sits" there and contains some data. You will evalutate such constraints, when you retrieve the attribute at a later time.

The emit a warning message, when such a constraint isn't met, you can implement a custom analyzer, that you'll ship along. You can start [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Getting-Started-Writing-a-Custom-Analyzer-&-Code-Fix) to learn how to implement such an analyzer.

Comment: Yeah this makes sense. Thanks for pointing me to custom roslyn analyzers, I think this is what I will try.